# Google Analytics code inside iFrame on FireFox raises: uncaught exception: DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics

The forum pages on my website are loaded inside an iFrame and have their own Google Analytics tracking code. I've now noticed (after the code's been there for a long time) that FireFox (v22) shows an exception in the console when loading such a page as: http://colnect.com/en/forum/index!

I've narrowed it down to this line of Google Analytics original code:

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

Which has the exact same result as the previous code they used:

```
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
```

I tried to figure out why the Exception is raised and how it may be treated but so far got nothing so it's time to ask if you know anything about it. I imagine that exception means that no forum pages (inside the frame) are tracked with Firefox.

Thanks